# MP1584 is giving 8.68V insted of 5V

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck

I designed schematic from monolithic power system website and placed components of same value.

- Vin=24 V
- Iout=2 A
- Vout=5 V
  and as suggested resistor value for FB pin I placed 124k and 23.7k in circuit but output voltage is showing 8.6 V and decreses as we decrease input voltage.
  I also tried 8.2k as R2 sugested in some website but that too ended with 8.6 V. Am I doing something wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have a load on the output? Some power supplies need a minimum load to maintain regulation.

Comment: i tried to add load of 100mA but after adding load it shows output voltage of 0.7V while input is 24V(does not show any drop)

Comment: Where exactly did you find that layout? The typical application schematic from the datasheet looks different.

Comment: Are you sure the exposed pad is properly soldered to ground?

Comment: yes its properly grounded and i copied the layout from monolithic system website.

Comment: Pin 1 in the schematic is connected to SW node. But layout shows that pin 1 is connected to ground. It seems you have rotated it 180 degrees.

Comment: good caught thanks

Comment: Was that the culprit? That rotated so-8?